# My bootstrap modal is working when i run it locally, but it won't open when i run it through git-hub?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can run my code just fine locally. Everything seems to be perfect. But as soon as I upload my repository to Git-Hub and try to run it with Git-hub pages, part of the website breaks? Specifically, the only issue is the Modal that's supposed to run when I click 'add to library' on the nav bar.

I tried deleting it off Git-Hub and reuploading it. I've tried moving the files around but nothing seems to work. I'm really not sure what the root of the issue is (?)

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-toggle="modal"
              data-target="#libraryModal"
            >
              Add to Library
            </button>

<!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal"
      id="libraryModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="libraryModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title text-primary" id="libraryModalLabel">
              Add to Library
            </h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control mb-2"
                  id="englishField"
                  placeholder="English"
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="spanishField"
                  placeholder="Spanish"
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addWord">
              Add Word
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addPhrase">
              Add Phrase
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Expected: It would open up a modal with two text boxes and two buttons. 
Actual: https://at-lowdesu.github.io/EstudiarEspanol/#study-inner (It doesn't open.)

Git-Hub Link: https://github.com/At-LowDeSu/EstudiarEspanol

Answer (score 1):

You have a mixed content error. All src should link to https://.. but you have one with http://

```
<script
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

Replace `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js` with `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery is not loaded or blocked in your page. The console said `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js”` 
You should fix this first, since bootstrap uses jQuery for its to run.

I've tried to inject the jQuery manually to the page and it works just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the jQuery script call.

```
<script
      src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap Modal :

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

you can refer more examples of the modal.